# Application Insights not tracking exceptions when used in ServiceStack application

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack, azure-application-insights

I currently have a problem where App Insights isn't showing the exceptions in .Net Core. I am also using ServiceStackCore to build my API.

This is what it currently looks like in the Azure portal under Application Insights:
[Screenshot of Azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0rPw.png%5C)

As you can see, the response codes all show 400, 403, 500. But there are no exceptions:

I have found a round-about route to get the Exceptions:

```
var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
...
try
{ ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   telemetry.TrackException(ex);
}
```

- I am wanting to know if ServiceStack has any inbuilt exception handling that might be muting exceptions that are supposed to be caught by app insights?
- And if there is any out of the box configuration that can be done in App Insights to show these exceptions without having to add the try-catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack lets you [register handlers to handle Exceptions](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#register-handlers-for-handling-service-exceptions):

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Handle Exceptions occurring in Services:

    this.ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add((httpReq, request, exception) => {
        //log your exceptions here
        ...
        return null; //continue with default Error Handling

        //or return your own custom response
        //return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, exception);
    });

    //Handle Unhandled Exceptions occurring outside of Services
    //E.g. Exceptions during Request binding or in filters:
    this.UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add((req, res, operationName, ex) => {
         res.Write($"Error: {ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
         res.EndRequest(skipHeaders: true);
    });
}
```

`ServiceExceptionHandlers` is fired for Service Exceptions whilst `UncaughtExceptionHandlers` are fired for non or unknown Service Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer and to add more claririty:

I have been overriding the HandleUncaughtException method as well as the ResolveResponseException method in AppHost in order to

- sanitize serialization errors as bad requests
- sanitize exceptions that I do not want to expose to clients (as internal server error)

  ```
  private TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

  public override void HandleUncaughtException(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, string operationName, Exception ex)
  {
      telemetry.TrackException(ex);
      if (!(ex is SerializationException))
      { // don't handle like BadRequest if not serialization exception
          base.HandleUncaughtException(httpReq, httpRes, operationName, ex);
          return;
      }
      httpRes.WriteError(new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.InnerException?.Message), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      httpRes.EndRequest(skipHeaders: true);
  }

  public override Exception ResolveResponseException(Exception ex)
  {
      telemetry.TrackException(ex);
      if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpError))
      { // Exception thrown using HttpError, do not sanitize

          return ex;
      }
      return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "The service has encountered an error, please contact your account manager if this persists.");
  }
  ```

And also I have added TrackException() telemetry to both methods which will cause the exceptions to get tracked to App Insights.

I think ServiceStack is somehow suppressing the exceptions from showing up in App Insights, and this implementation fixes that. The reason why I think this might be happening is because I also have another API that is run without ServiceStack (IdentityServer) which correctly tracks the exceptions.

Comment: An uncaught Exception would return an unparsable error page to the client. Most ServiceStack Exceptions are converted and [return structured Error Responses](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling), the handlers are how you can register and get notified of Exceptions.